# Print jobs cancelled if waiting too long?

Tags: software-update, printing, cups

I tend to send things to print, even when not connected to my printer (via usb). This allows it to print the minute I connect the printer, which is nice when I am on my laptop. It used to work, even if I didn't connect my printer for a day or two, but now it doesn't. The print jobs seem to die after 3 hours. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Printing in OS X is handled by CUPS, the Common Unix Printing System. Older versions of OS X had older versions of CUPS. A new <strike>It's not a bug, It's a</strike> *"feature"* was added in CUPS 1.6, which corresponds to Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion, in order to prevent stuck jobs.

The `MaxJobTime` option, which defaults to 10800 seconds (3 Hours), will cancel the active print job on a printer that has timed out. The next job in the queue will start, either printing or eventually timing out.

From the cups.conf man page:

> **MaxJobTime seconds**
>   Specifies  the  maximum time a job may take to print before it is canceled. The default is 10800 seconds (3 hours). **Set to 0 to disable cancellation of "stuck" jobs.**

Editing `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` to include `MaxJobTime 0` to disable this *"Feature"*.

*In my specific case, I used to be on 10.6.8 Snow Leopard until finally updating to 10.10 Mavericks, and wasn't aware of the change.*

Comment: @user3439894 is there a reason you keep editing that out?